# Can I detect my own rotation by looking at the cosmic background radiation?

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background

This is a simple question. Nevertheless it might be interesting to others.

If I move with constant speed across the cosmic background radiation, I see a "dipole": a blue shift of the CBR looking forward and a red shift looking backwards.

What do I see when just I rotate (without moving across the cosmic background radiation)?

Do I see something different if my rotation is accelerated instead of constant?

Comment: There are easier ways, like Sagnac effect based laser ring interferometers, or even mechanical ways, detecting Coriolis or centrifugal fictitious forces.

Comment: Yes, this is correct, of course. But is rotation also visible in the microwave background?

Comment: Yes, via the linear tangential velocity and Doppler effect. But direct detection of rotation would be much more sensitive.

Comment: How about a "point-like" detector? Is it reasonable to ask how an EM radiation field in thermal equilibrium looks to a rotating point-like observer? For example the observer could also be sitting just in a hohlraum here on earth. Do the perceptions of the field change like its spectrum? Or is the question meaningless related to any physical observer being non-pointlike.

Comment: @Georg E. Well,The observer may be point-like, but his rotation, while sitting on Earth, is not point-like. Perception would be modulated by the periodic tangential velocity.

Comment: @Poutnik When I was saying "here on earth" I meant as opposed to doing some sophisticated space mission to deal with the CMB. Do the thing in a drop tower if you want. Regarding your point "but his rotation is not point-like": What do you mean? I think you have to spell that out, as I m not sure I understand your language here.

Comment: But the OP means detection specifically wrt CMB. Neither I had in mind a space mission, but Earth based  experiment. Not point-like rotation is rotation with radius of Earth and tangential speed about 1.5 km/s on the equator. That is some influence on observed CMB perception.